# Sends mail message to senders mail box by mistake

Tags: php, email, gmail, google-apps, swiftmailer

I am sending two emails. A receipt to the customer and a receipt for the webshop owner.

The E-mail messages are generate and saved into a database with sender and recipient email addresses.

The pull the messages from the database and loop through them and send them with Swiftmailer through Google Apps (same system as Gmail).

But the receipt to the customer not only get's send to the customer but also to the senders mail box.

**Here is an edidted version of the customer mail:**

```
Return-Path: <sendermail@domain.com>
Received: from www.domain.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.14.2013.12.04.02.45.01
        for <receivermail@someotherdomain.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 04 Dec 2013 02:45:02 -0800 (PST)
Message-ID: <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@www.domain.com>
Date: Wed, 04 Dec 2013 11:45:01 +0100
Subject: Receipt
From: xxx xxx <sendermail@domain.com>
To: xxx xxx <receivermail@someotherdomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Some mail text
```

**Here is the code:**

```
// Send mail
public function mailer($to, $from, $subject, $message, array $param = array())
{
    // Initialize swiftmailer
    require_once '/path/to/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($param['smtp_server'], $param['smtp_port'], 'ssl')
        ->setUsername($param['smtp_username'])
        ->setPassword($param['smtp_password']);

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    // Create a message
    $content = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->setTo($to)
        ->setBody($message, $param['type']);

    // Send the message
    return $mailer->send($content);
}

// Execute tasks
public function execute_tasks()
{
    $functions = new Functions();
    $db = new Db();

    // Mail parameters
    $param = array
    (
        'smtp_server' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_username' => 'sendermail@domain.com',
        'smtp_password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    );

    // Get tasks
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 0";

    // Loop through tasks
    $sql = $db->query($sql);
    while ($row = $db->fetchArray($sql))
    {
        if ($row['type'] == 'mail' AND $row['response'] == '' AND $row['status'] == 0)
        {
            $to = array($row['to_email'] => $row['to_name']);
            $from = array($row['from_email'] => $row['from_name']);

            $param['type'] = $row['mime'];

            $status = $this->mailer($to, $from, $row['subject'], $row['content'], $param);

            if ($status == 1)
            {
                $db->query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id = ".$row['task_id']);
            }
            else
            {
                $db->query("UPDATE tasks SET status = 1 WHERE task_id = ".$row['task_id']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```